# how to make drag-drop list in HTML and send List order to asp.net core backend?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, drag-and-drop

I am working on an HTML file
When I show a list on a page, I want the user to be able to drag and drop items from the list to a part of the same page.
The list contains sample questions of a lesson, which the user selects by dragging one of the items and dropping them in another part of the same page, and finally creates an exam for himself by selecting questions from the list.
At the same time, it should be able to reorder  all the questions during the selection
Finally, how to send the final list order to the backend to be recorded in the database?
It should be noted that no code has been written, otherwise, I would have put part of the code here, I want a guide to starting writing the code.
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drag-drop, you can reference this sample: [Jquery UI Drag and Drop from One List to Another Listbox](https://www.nicesnippets.com/snippet/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-from-one-list-to-another-listbox)

For send list, you need jQuery ajax to send a post request to backend, such as

```
$.ajax('/jquery/submitData', {
    type: 'POST',  // http method
    data: { myData: 'This is my data.' },  // data to submit
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        $('p').append('status: ' + status + ', data: ' + data);
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            $('p').append('Error' + errorMessage);
    }
});
<p></p>
```

The posted data may include the userId and selections.

For webapi, you can use efcore to automatically create CRUD api controller which connect to a database. [Getting Started with Entity Framework Core](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/48889.getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-database-first-development.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your complete guidance
Before reading this guide, I found out from my search on the internet that you can create a drag-and-drop list with Library Sortable.js.